# GAE is not serving my robots.txt

Tags: google-app-engine

I have the following defined in my app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: img/favicon.ico
  upload: noop

- url: /apple-touch-icon.png
  static_files: img/apple-touch-icon.png
  upload: noop

- url: /images
  static_dir: img

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: media/robots.txt
  upload: noop

- url: /humans.txt
  static_files: media/humans.txt
  upload: noop
```

There are other mappings after the declaration for `/humans.txt` but I'll remove them for brevity.

The `noop` directory is an empty directory.

However my browser gives me a 404 when I try to access these urls:

1. http://myapp.appspot.com/humans.txt
2. http://myapp.appspot.com/robots.txt

Why ?

Comment: have you had a look at the GAE log?

Comment: One of the errors read: Static file referenced by handler not found: media/humans.txt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you're using static files, upload should match the static_files location:

```yaml
- url: /robots.txt
    static_files: media/robots.txt
    upload: media/robots.txt

- url: /humans.txt
    static_files: media/humans.txt
    upload: media/humans.txt
```

Comment: It's required for that, too.  Not sure why it'd work w/out.  Caching?

Comment: i think you should a look here as well. stackoverflow.com/questions/887328/favicon-ico-not-found-error-in-app-engine

Comment: @Frankie It worked for favicon.ico because the `/images` handler had already included your favicon as a static file.

Comment: Can I do it from root folder? Without media/?